# Not able to access a Linux directory

Tags: linux

There are two linux users

```
cloudera
omega
```

Both the above users are under the group batchusers

```
[omega@node1 projects]$ ls -ltr
drwxrwsr-x+  9 cloudera        batchusers        4096 May  5 10:53  omega_events
[omega@node1 projects]$ cd omega_events
bash: cd: omega_events: Permission denied
[omega@node1 projects]$ cd omega_events
bash: cd: omega_events: Permission denied
[omega@node1 projects]$
```

I see that omega user is not able to access the folder omega_events

hence I logged in as cloudera user and gave 777 permission to omega user

```
[cloudera@node1 projects]$ chmod 777 omega_events 
[cloudera@node1 projects]$ ls -ltr
drwxrwsrwx+  9 cloudera        batchusers        4096 May  5 10:53 omega_events
```

After that I logged in as omega user ,but still i am not able to access the folder omega_events

```
[omega@node1 projects]$ ls -ltr
drwxrwsrwx+  9 cloudera        batchusers        4096 May  5 10:53   omega_events
[omega@node1 projects]$ cd omega_events
bash: cd: omega_events: Permission denied
[omega@node1 projects]$


[omega@node1 projects]$ id omega
uid=1928292922(omega) gid=1928292922(omega) groups=1928292922(omega),1478288372(cc-manager),1478288372(batchusers),1478221121(emerge),1438902221(data_analytics)


[omega@node1 projects]$ getfacl omega_events
 # file: omega_events
 # owner: cloudera
 # group: batchusers
 user::rwx
 user:omega:rw-
 group::r-x
 group:batchusers:rw-
 mask::rwx
 other::rwx
 default:user::rwx
 default:user:omega:rw-
 default:group::r-x
 default:group:batchusers:rw-
 default:mask::rwx
 default:other::r-x
```

Could some one help me on this

Comment: You have 's' permission for a group instead of 'x'

Comment: You also have extended acl set on omega_events. What does `getfacl omega_events` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Removing the set-group-ID bit

chmod preserves set-group-ID bits unless you explicitly clear them, so `chmod 777 omega_events` did not help.

You need instead to clear the set-group-ID bit as cloudera and then repeat chmod to give traversal rights (**x**) to all `batchusers`.

```
[cloudera@node1 projects]$ chmod g-s omega_events 
[cloudera@node1 projects]$ chmod 775 omega_events
```

After this you should get

```
[cloudera@node1 projects]$ ls -ltr
drwxrwxr-x+  9 cloudera        batchusers        4096 May  5 10:53 omega_events
```

#### Fixing Access Control Lists

Another issue is that you have Access control lists on `omega_events`. This is indicated by a `+` sign at the end of the mode line.

The following rules cause permission denied to user `omega`

```
user:omega:rw-
group:batchusers:rw-
```

You can remove them with

```
[cloudera@node1 projects]$ setfacl -x u:omega omega_events
[cloudera@node1 projects]$ setfacl -x g:batchusers omega_events
```

You should get

```
[cloudera@node1 projects]$ getfacl omega_events
 # file: omega_events
 # owner: cloudera
 # group: batchusers
 user::rwx
 group::r-x
 mask::rwx
 other::rwx
 default:user::rwx
 default:user:omega:rw-
 default:group::r-x
 default:group:batchusers:rw-
 default:mask::rwx
 default:other::r-x
```

Also to remove default ACLs use the following command

```
[cloudera@node1 projects]$ setfacl -k omega_events
```

Comment: Ok. I tried this approach, I usually log in as sudo su - omega                          Still getting same error after applying the above . but I see that 's' is removed .

Comment: I updated the question as well

Comment: The primary group of omega is "omega"